# How to get Last Three missed call details from call log

Tags: android

i want to get last three missed calls details.and also i want to get these (values, Person name phone no and Time of call,date).

Please help me 
thanks..

Comment: so , http://whatyouhavetry.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**java file**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    call = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    call.setText(sb);
}
```

**xml file**

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```